# Prevent checking others checbox if textarea is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

A form with some textareas and a sumbit button are all disabled, each of textarea has a checkbox aside.

When checkbox is checked:

1- A message shows (You should not let activated textarea empty)

2- Submit button remains disabled

3- When start writing message hides and button enable.

When checkbox is unchecked :

1- message hides

2- textarea related to it is cleared if it has some texts

3-button returns to disabled

Everything is perfect so far with my codes below. 
Now, how can i prevent from checking others checkboxes if there is already one that is already checked with an empty textarea ?
The logic is if a textarea is enabled it must receive text.

```js
//handling checkbox
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(".textareaalert").text("Don't let this activated textarea empty");
    $(".textareaalert").slideDown("slow");
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".textareaalert").slideUp("slow");
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
    $("textarea").val('');

  }
});
//handling textarea
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
  var textareaLength = $(this).val().length;
  if (textareaLength == 0) {
    $(".textareaalert").text("Don't let this activated textarea empty");
    $(".textareaalert").slideDown("slow");
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".textareaalert").slideUp("slow");
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textareaalert" style="display:none"></div>
<form class="horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Infancia</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="infancia" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="checkbox"> <label>Activo</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  // more text area below
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a checking in `checkbox` change event using `$('input:checkbox:checked')` and `filter()` method to find is there any checked `checkbox` with empty `textarea`. If there is any then don't allow the `checkbox` to be checked.

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    
    //check is there any checked checkbox with empty textarea
    var length = $('input:checkbox:checked').not(this).filter(function() {
      return !$(this).closest('.form-group').find('textarea').val();
    }).length;

    //don't allow the checkbox to be checked
    if (length > 0) {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
      return;
    }

    $(".textareaalert").text("Don't let this activated textarea empty");
    $(".textareaalert").slideDown("slow");
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".textareaalert").slideUp("slow");
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
    $("textarea").val('');
  }
});

$("textarea").keyup(function() {
  var textareaLength = $(this).val().length;
  if (textareaLength == 0) {
    $(".textareaalert").text("Don't let this activated textarea empty");
    $(".textareaalert").slideDown("slow");
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".textareaalert").slideUp("slow");
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textareaalert" style="display:none"></div>
<form class="horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Infancia</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="infancia"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>Activo</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Infancia</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="infancia"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>Activo</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input id="submit" type="submit" disabled/>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much. This is exactly what i need. But i have 2 others checkbox which are not linked to any textarea how can remove them from the function ?

Comment: Use different classes for different type of checkboxes.

Comment: Ok, I can use a different class for different type of checkbox, that's true, but the checkbox connected to  a textarea are too many. How can use only the checkbox that are not connected to any textarea to remove them from the fuction. I try but i fail.

Comment: Use a class for other checkbox say `noTextarea`. Then use `$('input:checkbox').not('.noTextarea').change()`.